# Using a draw function in C#

Tags: c#, debugging

I made a function that draws a rectangle with rounded corners using examples I got researching here, now I want to call this function with a button click, but I'm not sure how to provide the arguments to the function, can someone help in how to I call this function?

```
public void DrawCond(Graphics g, Pen p, float width, float height, float x, float y)
{
    // Auxiliary variables
    float radius;
    if (width>=3.55)    
    {
        radius = 1F;
    }
    else if (width>2.25)
    {
        radius = 0.8F;       
    }
    else if (width>1.61)
    {
        radius = 0.65F;      
    }
    else
    {
        radius = 0.5F;
    }

    GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();

    //Draw lines
    gp.AddLine(x + radius, y, x + width - 2 * radius, y); //bottom horizontal line
    gp.AddLine(x + radius, y + height, x + width - 2 * radius, y + height); //top horizontal line
    gp.AddLine(x + width, y + radius, x + width, y + height - 2 * radius); //inner vertical line
    gp.AddLine(x + radius, y + radius, x + radius, y + height - 2 * radius); //outer vertical line

    //Draw arcs
    gp.AddArc(x, y + radius, radius, radius, 90, 90); //bottom left corner
    gp.AddArc(x + width - radius, y + radius, radius, radius, 0, 90); //bottom right corner
    gp.AddArc(x, y + height, radius, radius, 180, 90); //top left corner
    gp.AddArc(x + width - radius, y + height, radius, radius, 270, 90); //top right corner

    g.DrawPath(p, gp);

    gp.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: What is your problem? Just handle button `Click` event and call your function.

Comment: `Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(this.Handle);`  `Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red, 2.0f);` you know the rest.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev My problem is that I'm not sure how should I provide the arguments. Mainly "Graphics g" and "Pen p". I never did any code that draw on the form, my idea was to click in a button and make the function DrawCond draw the rounded corner rectangle into a panel using  the paint event

Comment: @kennyzx This worked, I changed to Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics(); so it will draw the rectangle in a panel instead of the form itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `Graphics` from panel you want to draw to like `var g = panel.CreateGraphics()` and pass it to your function.

Also you can create `Pen` by using one of its constructors. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pen(v=vs.110).aspx) for reference about Pen.

Comment: Thanks. This worked, it didn't draw the rectangle properly, but I was able to call the function into the panel and made it only update after the button_click event.